# Tables with multiple relationships

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables AdmissionExams and PeriodicalExams:

```
create table dbo.AdmissionExams
(
  Id int identity not null 
  AnalysisId int null,            FK to Analyses Table
  ClassificationId int not null,  FK to Classifications Table
  ProfessorId int not null,       FK to Professors Table    
  StudentId int not null,         FK to Students Table  
  -- Other admission exam columns
)

create table dbo.PeriodicalExams
(
  Id int identity not null 
  AnalysisId int null,            FK to Analyses Table
  ClassificationId int not null,  FK to Classifications Table
  ProfessorId int not null,       FK to Professors Table    
  StudentId int not null,         FK to Students Table  
  -- Other periodical exam columns
)
```

One exam has no Analisys or one Analisys. And one Analisys has only one Exam.
One exam has always one and only one Classification. And one Classification has only one Exam.

One exam has one and only one Student and only one Professor.
But one student and one professor can have multiple exams.

Is my business model ok? I am not sure about the FKs.

The Analysis and Classification table are the same for both type of exams.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you that use inherited table in Table per type format.

```
create table dbo.Exams
(
  Id int identity not null 
  AnalysisId int null,            FK to Analyses Table
  ClassificationId int not null,  FK to Classifications Table
  ProfessorId int not null,       FK to Professors Table    
  StudentId int not null,         FK to Students Table  
)

create table dbo.AdmissionExams
(
  Id int not null 
  -- Other admission exam columns
)

create table dbo.PeriodicalExams
(
  Id int not null 
  -- Other periodical exam columns
)

ALTER TABLE dbo.AdmissionExams ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_AdmissionExams_Exam] FOREIGN KEY(Id) REFERENCES dbo.exam (Id)
ALTER TABLE dbo.PeriodicalExams ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_PeriodicalExams_Exam] FOREIGN KEY(Id) REFERENCES dbo.exam (Id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather You should have one exam table and a column to define its type. Depending on the amount of information you have to capture for Classification and Analysis it might be be better to add them directly to the exam tables also (Given the 1 to 1 relationship).

```
create table dbo.Exams
(
  Id int identity not null 
  ExamType varchar(20) null,
  AnalysisInfo varchar(20) null,            
  ClassificationInfo varchar(20) null,  
  ProfessorId int not null,       FK to Professors Table    
  StudentId int not null,         FK to Students Table  
)
```